# close function of dialog being executed after dialog is closed upon ESC key press (in chrome only)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-dialog

I got a div with a certain class, i have delegated a click event to it so when it is being clicked i toggle its class with another one and open a dialog , Now when the dialog is being closed I toggle the div class back to the original

Now to the interesting part... If i hit the esc button on the keyboard the classes continue to toggle... this happens only in Chrome browser

Instructions to reproduce :
In Chrome:
click the div -> a dialog will be open -> close it -> start hitting esc button -  the color of the div will be changed cause the dialog close function is being executed (and it cause the div classes to toggle)

In FF and IE it works just fine and no esc issues are present

Here is the js code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).delegate(".dashboard_widget", "click", function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('dashboard_widget').toggleClass('dashboard_widget_clicked');
     showDialog();
  });

});
function showDialog(){
    $("#dialogID").dialog({
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
             }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $("#myID").toggleClass('dashboard_widget_clicked').toggleClass('dashboard_widget');
        }
    });
}
```

[I reproduced it in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/yYeQQ/5/)

Thanks ahead,

Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it , thanks to Rory idea

set the .data with false/true in order to tell when the dialog is open/close

here is the main snippet of the code (js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).delegate(".dashboard_widget", "click", function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('dashboard_widget').toggleClass('dashboard_widget_clicked');
     showDialog();
  });

});
function showDialog(){
    $("#myID").data('closed',false);    
    $("#dialogID").dialog({
        buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            if($("#myID").data('closed')!==true){
                $("#myID").toggleClass('dashboard_widget_clicked').toggleClass('dashboard_widget');
                $("#myID").data('closed',true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle Full Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/yYeQQ/8/)

Comment: Nice workaround. It may be worth raising the issue you had with the jQueryUI devs.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `escape` key is attached to the `close` method of the dialog. Because you have hooked your `toggleClass` to this method, the class is changed on each keypress.

Firefox and IE appear to ignore the `esc` keypress when the dialog is not opened, Chrome does not, hence the issue.

Without changing the code of the plugin I don't think there is much that can be done to fix this.

Comment: tnx for the information... It gave me an idea... will use the .data to set it with fale/true in order to tell if the dialog is opened , and in case its closed I wont execute the close code block , postig the solution in jsfiddle